# MVC 3 + jQuery = dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms

My page consist from these three blocks:

1. Page header
2. Page body
3. Page foot

In page header section I have several drop downs. Depends on selected values in these drop downs I have to load proper form, so what is the best way to make it?
Thank you!

Comment: Your title doesn't really describe what you're asking for. Consider revising? Also, are you asking how to load part of the page using jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect people [to do some effort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking their questions.

Answer (score 1):

may not be the best way but you can put the form in a partial view and `onChange` of selected value render the partial view using `ajax`

here is an example http://iridescence.no/post/Partial-Rendering-with-ASPNET-MVC-and-jQuery.aspx